# DATE to NUMBER / pseudo-number convertion

Tags: oracle

To my own surprise, I don't understand how it works:

```
SELECT NVL2 (null, SYSDATE - (SYSDATE - 1), SYSDATE)
  FROM dual;
```

How and why Oracle succeffully converts `DATE` to pseudo-number (`Typ=14`)? I've read `NVL2`, `Numeric Precedence` and `Implicit Data Conversion` documentation, but still have no idea how it works. There is `--` in implicit type conversion table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the query:

```
SELECT NVL2 (null, SYSDATE - (SYSDATE - 1), SYSDATE) result from dual;
```

`NVL2` (from [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions106.htm)):

- If `expr1` is not null, then `NVL2` returns `expr2`.
- If `expr1` is null, then `NVL2` returns `expr3`.  >> your query will return `EXPR3`

Next:

- if `expr2` is numeric, then Oracle determines which argument has the highest numeric precedence, implicitly converts the other argument to that datatype, and returns that datatype.

As `expr2` really is numeric (result is `1`); you don't even need database involved into it, it says

```
sysdate - (sysdate - 1) = sysdate - sysdate + 1 = 1
```

then `expr3` is also implicitly converted to number. `sysdate`, being a function that returns `date` datatype, is converted to **Julian** date.

```
SQL> SELECT NVL2 (null, SYSDATE - (SYSDATE - 1), SYSDATE) result from dual;

    RESULT
----------
2458770,44

SQL> SELECT to_char(sysdate, 'J') result from dual;

RESULT
-------
2458770
```

Makes sense?

Comment: But I don' understand why DATE converts to NUMBER cause there is '--' in implicit type conversion table.

Comment: True, there is `--` in the table. Unfortunately, I can't explain that. Hopefully, someone else can.